# Google Glass number picker with gestures

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I would like to know if it's possible to use glass gestures on the touch-pad to implement a number picker. The goal is that when you swipe forward and back a number displayed on the screen increases when you swipe forwards and decreases when you swipe back.

Comment: Take a look at the official timer sample here https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-timer-sample  
Setting the timer is performed with gestures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the Timer sample's [`SetTimerActivity`](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-timer-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/glass/sample/timer/SetTimerActivity.java) uses a [`GestureDetector`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector) to detect motion events on the touchpad and change the value accordingly.

The main logic is in the [`ScrollListener#onScroll`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/touchpad/GestureDetector.ScrollListener) implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(float displacement, float delta, float velocity) {
    mReleaseVelocity = velocity;
    if (!mOptionMenuOpen) {
        // Change the value, in this case, the current time in second.
        addTimeSeconds(delta * Math.min(Math.abs(velocity), MAX_DRAG_VELOCITY));
    }
    return true;
}
```

The other listener implementations are used for adding some physic simulation such as an inertial scrolling effect when the user swipes fast enough.